# Emacs Helm (anything): Desired candidates are excluded for autocompletion. Why?

Tags: emacs

I have a file in my home directory called `.gitconfig`. When I try to open this file with Emacs with `helm-mode` activated, this file is eventually unmatched, as I type it.

In the minibuffer I start typing the path (<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>)

```
Find file: /home/.g
```

and it shows me:

```
.gconf
.gitconfig
.gnome2-private
```

etc.

However, as soon I type `i` (i.e. typing `/home/.gi` to eventually type `.gitconfig`), Helm removes `.gitconfig` from the autocompletion list and leaves me with `.gnome2-private`.

Why does this happen? How can I have Helm never exclude a file from the current directory where I am hoping to open a file?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this after recreating the directory structure you specified.

If you clone the helm github repo found [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), then execute
`./emacs-helm.sh`, does it still repro?  If not, can you add back your
config until it does?  This would be a bug.

Also, it would be best to file a helm issue and discuss it there.

Comment: This is odd. If I start Emacs using `./emacs-helm.sh` then it works fine, but if I start it by running the Emacs binary it doesn't. Why does Helm provide a shell script to start Emacs? What is the difference of just calling Emacs directly?

Comment: The shell script is for debugging purposes.  It gives you a basic helm setup without any customizations similar to `emacs -Q`.